# iOS9 UIPageViewController crashes while accesing view

Tags: ios, ios9, uipageviewcontroller

I have iOS9 app that works with storyboard with 1 controller.

I have a View Controller with the following `viewDidLoad` method:

```
@interface TestVC ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

@end

@implementation TestVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.pageViewController =
    [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                    navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                  options:nil];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[vc1] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    self.pageViewController.view;

}
```

When I run my app it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on line `self.pageViewController.view`. Actually, it crashes on any line that access pageVC's view.

iOS8 works as expected.

Any ideas?